# Core Bluetooth scanForPeripherals yields no results when given CBUUIDs

Tags: swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I have a speaker that supports the following profiles according to [the manual](https://images.aukey.com/en/downloads/SK-M12%20User%20Manual.pdf): A2DP, AVRCP, HSP, and HFP.

I'm using [Bluetooth's Assigned Numbers Document](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-numbers/Assigned%20Number%20Types/Assigned%20Numbers.pdf) to create my CBUUIDs.

```swift
    let a2dpSinkUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x110B")
    let a2dpSourceUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x110A")
```

If I pass the sinkUUID into `scanForPeripherals(withServices: [a2dpSinkUUID])` my device is not found regardless of whether it's run on my mac or my iPhone even though it connects to them using iOS's built in Bluetooth functionality just fine. The device is powered on and discoverable and I'm able to see peripherals when I don't pass in any services. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When it appears in `didDiscoverPeripheral`, what's the advertisement data? In other words, if it doesn't advertise the CBUUID, it's normal that if you scan only the device that advertise that they have this service (no obligation on their side), you won't find it.

Answer (score 0):

These are all "classic" or BR/EDR profiles. Core Bluetooth cannot communicate with them. With a very narrow set of exceptions, it only works with BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) services. There is no way for an iOS app to interact directly with any of those profiles. You can only access them indirectly via AVAudioSession and the MediaPlayer framework. [I don't think anything on the iPhone supports HSP, including at the OS level.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387)